# about django's list_fields in making models for friends list, in project about making SNS

Tags: python, html, django, web

I'm making web-SNS like Instagram so I should make models that contains one user's all friends. I try to use list for containing user's friends:

[image]

yeah, i know i can't use and build list by using that way.

How to make use of list for save user's friends list or is there more good idea for saving user's friends list in user(not User, just real user)'s model?

Comment: No, typically you use a `ForeignKey`, or a `ManyToManyField`. `ArrayField` en `ListField`s are typically a bad idea.

Comment: See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Don't post images of your code.

Comment: Oh, that is very good idea!!!!! very very thanks~. after studying about that, I'll show you that i make~~

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, Oh my God~~!!!! i understand your advice!!!
maybe i can make follow, follower system~!!!!!!
very very thank you~!!!